# aptitude package install error

Tags: 11.10, package-management, aptitude

apt-get install -f gives following

```
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 flashplugin-downloader:i386
 flashplugin-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am unable to proceed from this point as I get above error repeatedly.

I am on 11.10 with amd64 system.

Comment: try "sudo dpkg --configure -a"

Comment: As the last comment mentioned, try sudo dpkg --configure -a
But please tell us if you enbaled Multiarch support in  11.10 or not and the exact the command that returns these errors.

Answer (score 0):

As the last comment mentioned, try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
But please tell us if you enbaled **Multiarch support** in  11.10 or not and the exact the command that returns these errors.
Are you using `sudo aptitude install something` or `sudo apt-get install something`